# There is a problem when running a node application on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, node-modules

I am trying to run a node site on an azure VM but I get this error when running > SkyCrypt@1.0.0 start

````
> node init && node index

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1109
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: /home/nim1com/SkyCrypt/credentials.json: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 216
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1106:22)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nim1com/SkyCrypt/init.js:15:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! SkyCrypt@1.0.0 start: `node init && node index`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the SkyCrypt@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nim1com/.npm/_logs/2021-01-19T09_41_40_472Z-debug.log```
````

What would be the answer to this problem? I have tried deleting package-lock.json and node_modules

credentials.json

```
{
    "hypixel_api_key": "26ed366f-80ed-4b49-b912-ef46292c6225",
    "recaptcha_site_key": "",
    "recaptcha_secret_key": "",
    "dbUrl": "mongodb+srv://dbStats:*********@cluster0.4kwsp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    "dbName": vmstats",
    "session_secret": "36e47c144b9b9b3e0b9c8bf24c6ac2860c0f76a55b74dcea4007bf355af76789"
}
```

Comment: read the error its complaining about the `v` in `"dbName": vmstats",` because is not valid json

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems your /home/nim1com/SkyCrypt/credentials.json file need to be corrected ...

Answer (score -1):

read the error its complaining about the v in "dbName": vmstats", because is not valid json – Lawrence Cherone